# Does Cassandra primary key size affects write performance?

Tags: cassandra, primary-key

I need to store some data with next columns `c1, c2, c3, c4, c5`. I want to minimize data size on disc using `COMPACT STORAGE`. The next PK is enough for my future queries:

```
(c1, c2), c3
```

But for `COMPACT STORAGE` using I should have only one non primary key column. I can add c4 to clustering key for it:

```
(c1, c2), c3, c4
```

But I don't need to do range search for c4 field and I doubt that it will affect write performance. Are my doubts justified?

Comment: What version are you using? Post 3.0 compact storage is meaningless. Nothing about that will affect write performance (not measurably at least), just read performance. Order the keys based on how your going to query them, the size on disk will be more impacted by you compaction strategy at that level if theres any updates or deletes.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I'm using C* 3.5. Why compact storage is meaningless? And why it will affect read performance? As I understood C* should select correct place for writing new value according to clustering keys sort order. But how it influence on read performance?

Comment: 3.0+ there was a rewrite of the storage engine and now everything is compact storage essentially. There is no difference enabling it or not, it just remains there for compatibility purposes with old version really. C* does not use in place writes, its uses log structured merge trees (LSM tree). Writes all cost the same, they append the mutation to a commit log for durability and update an in memory structure (memtable) thats periodically flushed to disk. The flushed (sstables) are periodically merged (compaction). https://academy.datastax.com/ is good source to learn read/write path.